# Lost on how to access newly created chatrooms

Tags: support, chat

I just had a doubtful question on meta. 1h after I deleted it, some user added a comment asking me "Please don't post this type of question here again. Thanks.", to which I would well agree, because I felt the question in question would not be appropriate on main chemistry, and also not on meta. So, in doubt and to minimize harm, I decided to post on meta. Now I had a lot more than one idea what the poster could have had in mind when saying "this kind of question" and "here".
("here" could be anywhere from "meta.chemistry." over to "chemistry" and "*.stackoverflow" to "anywhere in this universe".)

So I resolved to contact that user via creating a chat room but, apparently, failed epically. It looks like the chat room is created, but I don't see how to access it.

And this is where I sit and where I'm currently lost.

Edit: to clarify, I need some technical support on how to make the newly created chat-room ( http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34030/what-exactly-have-i-done-wrong ) accessible or at least to delete it if it is dysfunctional the way I created it.

Comment: You're not to blame. SE interface is horribly confusing, esp. about chats. Meet me there.

Comment: I've been made to find out ... somehow.I'm on the chat right now. Everything new is *new* per definition.

Comment: Urrgh, yes, I have an inborn an excessively trained instinct to ignore anything that even faintly looks like an advertise. To me, this is something like the "someone-else-problem" from "The Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy". So I missed the friendly and invitingly green input field at first.